# change Apache ServerTokens

Tags: apache2

I'm following [this](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_in_Ubuntu) tutorial.

There doesn't seem to be a `conf.d` directory so I'm not sure how to:

> Change ServerTokens OS to read ServerTokens Prod

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

In newer Ubuntu versions `conf.d` directory was replaced by `conf-available` and `conf-enabled`.

First, make sure `security.conf` is enabled:

```
sudo a2enconf security
```

Then edit `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/security.conf` and change `ServerTokens OS` to `ServerTokens Prod`.